# want to send outlook meeting invite through c#

Tags: c#, outlook, angular6

i wanted to send an outlook meeting invite through our website , i have tried smtp but meeting invitation is in attachment , i wanted a proper meeting invitation so i have tried interop.outlook .dll and it's working fine locally , because locally outlook is install and configure , but once i have deployed the code it's not working , and server end i can't configure outlook , i won't find any any  setting from where we can set  email and password manually .

please help me what to do in this scenario. is there is any way to achieve this. ?

Comment: Please read the [tour] and most importantly please provide some [mcve] of what is "not working" when deployed

Comment: i am trying to send an outlook meeting invite through SMTP , i am getting the meeting invitation but in an attachment format , but i don't want that meeting invite is in attachment  .

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Outlook in a service (such as IIS). SMTP should work, but you need to ensure your appointment is sent as the primary MIME part, not as an attachment.

Comment: One definitely *can* use Outlook (or other Office apps) in headless environment… It is not supported and pretty much guaranteed to fail in all or most scenarios... Does not stop anyone from trying so :)

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko , i have try to use mime as well , but it won't work as expected , since shall i get any proper reference so i can follow the same. that's very help full for me.

Comment: @abhi sg - why would;t it work? SMTP is what Outlook ends up using if you send between mailboxes. Post your existing code.

Comment: @Dmitry streblechenk , i am sharing my final code here , every things works as expected , but in mail i am getting my full html tag.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Sharing your code where? What works as expected?